# Add array to array without keys

Tags: php, arrays

I know this must be a huge newbie question, but I didn't find the correct answer. Let's see. I have an array set:

```
$global_array = array();
```

Then, I want to add an arry inside `$global_array`, but I dont want the keys. So, the result I want to get is:

```
 $global_array = array(
   array(
      'bla',
      'bla'
   )
 );
```

Sorry for the noob question. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the keys the be numerical? Theres no such thing as an array without keys, the example you post above has numerical keys

Comment: i think you just want `$global_array[]='bla';`

Comment: Before asking this kind of questions, please look in the manual. See [here for array documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Answer (score 2):

This should help:

```
$global_array[] = array('bla','bla');
```

All arrays will have keys...

If not defined as default 0,1,2,3...

Comment: This would give me keys. I dont want it.

Comment: there in no such thing as an array with out keys in php

Comment: all arrays will have keys

Comment: how would you find the value with out the "key", it be  like a variable without the variable name

Comment: PHP arrays have two types of keys-- incremental numeric keys (like above) or alphanumeric like so: $x[keyname]='value'; or like above with $x[0]='value'; but you do have to have at least one of those.